# How can I fix the display of these Google ads so they don't look like junk?

Tags: html, google-adsense, design

How do I fix these ads so they don't look like crap and are cut off?

[image: Imgur]

I checked the height and width, and the outer dimensions are in fact the correct size, but internally, they load iframe and somewhere along the way it doesn't fit. Other AdSense ads don't look this bad. It only happens when the text does not fit.

Here is the HTML that AdSense generates:

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-99999999999999" data-ad-slot="2594965732" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"><ins id="aswift_1_expand" style="display:inline-table;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent"><ins id="aswift_1_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:90px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:728px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="728" height="90" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_1" name="aswift_1" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;"></iframe></ins></ins></ins>
```

Chrome doesn't appear to copy the #document of the iframe.

---

In the ad editor, you can click Text Ad Styles and there is an option for changing the font and size. I did not remember those. They were set to "Optimal", but it doesn't say how it  determines what is optimal! Obviously it is not optimal. So I changed it to small font size and they appear better.

[image: snaggy]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have the answer to this.

In the ad editor, you can click Text Ad Styles and there is an option for changing the font and size. I did not remember those. They were set to "Optimal", but it doesn't say how it  determines what is optimal! Obviously it is not optimal. So I changed it to small font size and they appear better.

[image: snaggy]